# Converted test code generates an error (C# to VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net

I have converted a C# code to VB.net and have applied the small adjustments required.

But when I test the code, it generates an error at the point where these instructions are:

```
If Not capture.Cued Then
    capture.Filename = counter & ".wmv"
```

I am no expert in DirectShow and I need that code to continue learning. Please Could anyone give me their generous help?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports DirectX.Capture
Imports DShowNET

Public Class MyWebCam
    Inherits Form
    ' Muaz Khan (@muazkh) - http://muaz-khan.blogspot.com 


    Private capture As Capture = Nothing
    Private filters As Filters = Nothing

    Private counter As Integer = 1
    Private timer As New Timer()

    Private deviceNumber As Integer = 0

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    '============================================================================


    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        filters = New Filters()

        If filters.VideoInputDevices IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                preview(deviceNumber)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Maybe any other software is already using your WebCam." & vbLf & vbLf & " Error Message: " & vbLf & vbLf & ex.Message)
            End Try
        Else
            btnStartVideoCapture.Enabled = False
            MessageBox.Show("No video device connected to your PC!")
        End If

        timer.Interval = 600000
        ' 10 minutes!
        AddHandler timer.Tick, Function(obj, evt)
                                   If btnStartVideoCapture.Text = "STOP" Then
                                       counter += 1

                                       If capture IsNot Nothing AndAlso counter > 1 Then
                                           capture.[Stop]()
                                           If Not capture.Cued Then
                                               capture.Filename = counter & ".wmv"
                                           End If
                                           capture.Cue()
                                           capture.Start()
                                       End If
                                   End If

                               End Function

        If filters.VideoInputDevices IsNot Nothing Then
            For i = 0 To filters.VideoInputDevices.Count - 1
                Dim device = filters.VideoInputDevices(i)

                Dim btn = New Button()

                btn.Text = i.ToString()
                btn.ForeColor = Color.White
                btn.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue
                btn.Width = 25

                AddHandler btn.Click, Function(obj, evt)
                                          Dim thisButton = DirectCast(obj, Button)

                                          If Integer.Parse(thisButton.Text) <> deviceNumber Then
                                              If capture IsNot Nothing Then
                                                  capture.Dispose()
                                                  capture.[Stop]()
                                                  capture.PreviewWindow = Nothing
                                              End If

                                              deviceNumber = Integer.Parse(thisButton.Text)
                                              preview(deviceNumber)
                                          End If

                                      End Function

                FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    '============================================================================


    Private Sub preview(deviceNo As Integer)
        Try

            ' MessageBox.Show("deviceNo = > " + deviceNo);
            capture = New Capture(filters.VideoInputDevices(deviceNo), filters.AudioInputDevices(0))

            capture.PreviewWindow = Panel1

            If btnStartVideoCapture.Text = "STOP" Then
                counter += 1
                If Not capture.Cued Then
                    capture.Filename = counter & ".wmv"
                End If
                capture.Cue()
            End If

            capture.Start()
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub

    '============================================================================


    Private Sub btnStartVideoCapture_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStartVideoCapture.Click
        startOrStopCapturing(capture)
    End Sub

    '============================================================================


    Private Sub startOrStopCapturing(capture As Capture)
        btnStartVideoCapture.Visible = False

    '**** THE ERROR BEGINS TO APPEAR HERE ************
    '****
    '****
        If capture IsNot Nothing Then
            capture.[Stop]()
        End If
        If timer.Enabled Then
            timer.[Stop]()
        End If

        If btnStartVideoCapture.Text = "START" Then
            btnStartVideoCapture.Text = "STOP"
            btnStartVideoCapture.BackColor = Color.Maroon

            Try
                If Not capture.Cued Then
                    capture.Filename = counter & ".wmv"
                End If

                capture.Cue()
                capture.Start()

                timer.Start()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error Message: " & vbLf & vbLf & ex.Message)
            End Try
        Else
            btnStartVideoCapture.Text = "START"
            btnStartVideoCapture.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue
        End If
        btnStartVideoCapture.Visible = True
    End Sub

    '============================================================================

    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.btnStartVideoCapture = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel()
        Me.Panel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'btnStartVideoCapture
        '
        Me.btnStartVideoCapture.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkSlateBlue
        Me.btnStartVideoCapture.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.btnStartVideoCapture.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.btnStartVideoCapture.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(498, 421)
        Me.btnStartVideoCapture.Name = "btnStartVideoCapture"
        Me.btnStartVideoCapture.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(89, 38)
        Me.btnStartVideoCapture.TabIndex = 2
        Me.btnStartVideoCapture.Text = "START"
        Me.btnStartVideoCapture.UseVisualStyleBackColor = False
        '
        'FlowLayoutPanel1
        '
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 421)
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Name = "FlowLayoutPanel1"
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(502, 38)
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 3
        '
        'Panel1
        '
        Me.Panel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, -3)
        Me.Panel1.Name = "Panel1"
        Me.Panel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(587, 418)
        Me.Panel1.TabIndex = 4
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(585, 458)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Panel1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.FlowLayoutPanel1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnStartVideoCapture)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Private WithEvents btnStartVideoCapture As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents FlowLayoutPanel1 As System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel
    Friend WithEvents Panel1 As System.Windows.Forms.Panel

End Class
```

Comment: And what error might that be?

Comment: Add Exception into Catch and copy/paste your error.

Comment: Another case of NullReferenceException. The capture instance is nothing but is not tested against Nothing

Comment: Also, the comments in your code and the description in your question point to different parts.

Comment: You should rename your variable `capture` - in VB it can make things awkward to have a variable name the same as a class name. If you used [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) then the IDE might even point out a problem with that in your code. Also `filters` and `timer`. In C#, variable names are case-sensitive; in VB they are not.

Answer (score 1):

In the `startStopCapturing` you dont't check if the `capture` **IsNothing**. The capture object is initialized when you enter the `preview` method at the form `Shown` event or at the timer event.
Everywhere you have code in place that checks the capture object for `IsNothing` and to avoid using it but, in `startStopCapturing`, you don't have this check to protect the code in the IF that change the button text.

```
Private Sub startOrStopCapturing(capture As Capture)
    btnStartVideoCapture.Visible = False
    If capture IsNot Nothing Then
        capture.[Stop]()
        capture.Dispose()
        capture = Nothing
        If timer.Enabled Then
            timer.[Stop]()
        End If
        btnStartVideoCapture.Text = "START"
        btnStartVideoCapture.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue
    Else
        Try
           capture = New Capture(filters.VideoInputDevices(deviceNumber), _ 
                                 filters.AudioInputDevices(0))

            capture.Filename = counter & ".wmv"
            capture.Cue()
            capture.Start()
            timer.Start()
            btnStartVideoCapture.Text = "STOP"
            btnStartVideoCapture.BackColor = Color.Maroon

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error Message: " & vbLf & vbLf & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
    btnStartVideoCapture.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Also this code in the inline button_click event seems to be wrong

```
 If capture IsNot Nothing Then
      capture.Dispose()
      capture.[Stop]()
      capture.PreviewWindow = Nothing
 End iF
```

Do not use a disposed object and set it to Nothing because without that you could fool again your code in belivieng that the capture object is valid

```
 If capture IsNot Nothing Then
      capture.[Stop]()
      capture.PreviewWindow = Nothing
      capture.Dispose()
      capture = Nothing
 End iF
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable contribution, but what I do not understand is why you repeated your code within startOrStopCapturing(), with that code snippet belongs exclusively to preview(DeviceNo). 

Note that the DeviceNo variable, there is only used in preview (DeviceNo). capture = New Capture(filters.VideoInputDevices(deviceNo), _ 
filters.AudioInputDevices(0))

Note that the DeviceNo variable, there is only used in preview(DeviceNo).

Comment: @OscarMeza right, it was a copy paste from your code. I can't test here. However it seems that you could use the global deviceNumber instead of deviceNo

Comment: I apologize for two reasons: 

1) Do not quite understand this Chat-Forum. 

2) My English is very bad, and I always use https://translate.google.co.ve to translate from Spanish.

Comment: No need to apologize. This site is used by people all over the world and not everyone is _madre lingua_ (like me for example). However the _programming_english_ is simple enough to let everyone express their concepts.

Comment: I get the same error in the same place: 

***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*** 

    ***capture.Filename = counter & "wmv"***

Comment: One thing is the English Programming, and quite another to write a narrative, with very detailed explanations.

Comment: Please, how can I put here for you the full C# code, which itself works fine?

Comment: Sorry but can't help you on debugging your code from here. Not at a PC with the required hardware.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I would prefer to forget this issue for now. Someday return to this interesting problem and I assure you that I will be solve. 

Greetings.